# How to write to gzip file from elixir code

Tags: gzip, elixir

I would like to write gzip file from elixir code.

I tried to following code, but it doesn't work well.

```
io_device = File.open!("/path/to/file.gzip", [:write, :compressed])
IO.write(io_device, "test")
```

`IO.write` returns `:ok`, but, `/path/to/file.gzip` is empty.

How can I write to gzip file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need one more step: close the file so that any buffered data gets written:

```
File.close io_device
```

Comment: Thanks! I can write to gzip file.

Answer (score 8):

You can also do whole thing in one step:

```
File.write "/path/to/file.gzip", "test", [:compressed]
```

Comment: Thank you. I can write with `File.write`